# highlight text at run time by pressing search button

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, web-deployment

I have made a small program that search value from a div...it show first location of the word
But i want to make that searched word highligheted after pressing search button at **all repeated location..**

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#searchdiv{background-color: #999999;left: 277px;margin: 39px 0 0 84px;padding:5px;width:500px;align:center;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function search()
{
    var keyword=document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    var str=document.getElementById("area").innerHTML;
    var n=str.search(keyword);
    alert('Location is :'+n);
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="searchdiv">
     <input type="text" id="keyword" name="text" size="70" />
     <input type="button" value="search" id="btn" name="button" onclick="search()"/>
     <br>
     <div style="width:444px;" id="area" name="textarea">rajendra kumar rahar from jhunjhunu</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

**i have tried so many times but couldnot get an idea to make highlight a specific text in div by javascript...????**
If anybody have please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
var high = "<div class='highlighted'>"+n+"</div>";
document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = str.replace(n,high);
```

Comment: yes it's good code.Thanks.....but sir i want to make all location highligheted..have you any idea?? –

Comment: replace will replace all value you have passed did you check that

Comment: yes, maine check kiya h....ye only starting value ko replace krke highlight krta h jiska index n h..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#searchdiv{background-color: #999999;left: 277px;margin: 39px 0 0 84px;padding:5px;width:500px;align:center;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function search()
{
    var keyword=document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    var str=document.getElementById("area").innerHTML;
    var n=str.search(keyword);
    var anshu=str.substring(n,(n+keyword.length)); 
    //alert('Word Found :'+anshu);

    var af = document.getElementById("area");
    af.innerHTML = str.slice(0, n) 
    af.innerHTML += '<b>' + anshu + '</b>';
    af.innerHTML += str.slice(n+keyword.length);
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="searchdiv">
     <input type="text" id="keyword" name="text" size="70" />
     <input type="button" value="search" id="btn" name="button" onclick="search()"/>
     <br>
     <div style="width:444px;" id="area" name="textarea">rajendra kumar rahar from jhunjhunu</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: yes anshuVersatile it's working fine...But for multiple location ??
if you have any idea..it will be reallly helpful

Comment: yes @anshuVersatile it's working fine...But for multiple location ?? if you have any idea..it will be reallly helpful –

Answer (score 1):

```
new_html = "<div class='highlighted'>" + n + "</div>";
```

Comment: ,Sir i don't want to print value of n....i want to make the searched text highligheted that don't have any id...

Comment: i wrapped your searched text in another <div> which is having highlighted class means css

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the innerHTML, add a tag, and concat it back. So, at the end of search put:

```
var a = document.getElementById("area");
a.innerHTML = str.slice(0, n) 
a.innerHTML += '<b>' + keyword + '</b>';
a.innerHTML += str.slice(n+keyword.length);
```

I don't see any easy way allow the dehighlighting of text, though.

Comment: yes it's good code.Thanks.....but sir i want to make all location highligheted..have you any idea??